# Send a fake SMS over bluetooth to android

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth

I'm building a installation for trade show where a PC with linux would send a SMS to a rooted android cellphone (lenovo a760). The problem is that there is no internet, no gsm network (there is but very expensive). Using WiFi is forbidden by trade show operator. Using cable and *adb* is my last hope, but not very convenient (cables are ugly).

I look for a solution that would allow PC to send/trigger android over bluetooth so the cellphone will act like it just got a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manged to use `gammu` to  connect over bluetooth and send an sms to myself. Python code:

```
import gammu
statemachine = gammu.StateMachine()
statemachine.SetConfig(
    0, {'Device': 'bt_addr', 'Connection': 'blueat'},
)
statemachine.Init()
statemachine.SendSMS({
    'Text': 'test', 
    'SMSC': {'Location': 1},
    'Number': '012345667',
})
```